# Вопрос по C# - inputBox и backspace

Tags: c#, input, клавиатура

Пишу калькулятор и мне нужно, чтобы в inputBox можно было вводить только цифры. Написал для этого обработчик:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
}
```

А теперь мне нужно, чтобы клавиша Backspace при последнем нажатии возвращала 0. То есть, к примеру было 123, и после 3 нажатий Backspace inputBox равнялся 0, а не очищался полностью.

Реально такое?

Либо просто как запретить inputBox быть пустым? Если все удалили, то inputBox принимает значение 0.

P.S. NumericUpDown не подходит.

Comment: Вместо TextBox используйте NumericUpDown и не мучайтесь.

Comment: "программа выбивает ошибку" - Ваша же программа, проверяйте textBox1.Text на пустую строку перед использованием/конвертацией.

Comment: Нужно обрабатывать не только Backspace, но и Delete (ведь им тоже можно очистить TextBox), и Ctrl+X (аналогично, можно очистить TextBox, вырезав всё выделенное содержимое), а также вырезание через контекстное меню. Намного проще использовать событие TextChanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что, если при `textBox1.Text == ""` устанавливать `textBox1.Text = "0"`? Мне кажется, должно помочь, и это проще, чем отлавливать нажатие BackSpace.
Заодно сразу обработаете и случай, когда текст был выделен и удалён Delete. Сделать это следует в событии TextChanged, как я полагаю.
То есть, код будет примерно таким:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0) {
        textBox1.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Простите, не могу проверить данный пример у себя, но суть решения, я думаю, мне удалось донести.

Comment: Это, в-общем, правильный подход. Однако, попробуйте улучшить свой ответ: укажите правильное событие (со ссылкой на документацию) и напишите корректный пример кода.

Comment: Про кроссплатформенность C# слышать не доводилось? Зачем людей в заблуждение вводить тем что у вас на другой системе mono не установлен?

Comment: Александр, постараюсь исправить ответ.

Дмитрий, я не ввожу никого в заблуждение. Более того, mono у меня установлен. Но я не вижу лично для себя смысла писать на C#, сидя под Linux.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо за рекомендации по исправлению. Исправил свой ответ.